# Raspberry Pi 3 unattainable

Tags: power, raspbian-jessie

I have a raspberry pi 3 with Jessie, on it runs cups to connect a printer to the network. From a while, systematically, after a while from the boot, it goes in standby or something, disconnects itself from the network and becomes unattainable via ssh, vnc and other else, and, of course with him, also cups and the printer; 
The leds remain red but the left one sometimes blinks and change from red to green/orange. 
The only way to get it back to work is to remove the power.

I have already tried this solution without success
[Https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/6670/64756](http://Https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/6670/64756)

Does anyone know how to fix it or at least if I can find some system log for tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using an appropriate power adapter- if it's marginal you can see intermittent problems as you describe. 2.5 amps seem to be currently recommended for the Pi 3.

If you're using the Pi with a monitor you might also see a small lightening bolt in the upper right of the screen- this is a OS supplied warning that the power adapter may be under-powered and not able to supply the needed current and voltage.

Comment: I change my power adapter, now i use a 2.5 amps, before was 1.2, but the issue still remain